# Performance of LWT in scylla/cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cockroachdb, scylla, paxos

Wanted to understand the why do we say the throughput of whole Cassandra/scylla/cockroachDB setup is dependent on LWT/linearised TX.

LWT will affect throughput of a hot key (index or row with a lot of queries), I do understand we can't increase throughput of a key using LWT in cassandra/scylla or any DB by horizontally scaling. My question is why can't we increase throughput of whole cluster by increasing the nodes in a cluster.

Adding more points on the question, if for an index paxos/raft is blocking an index and affecting throughput of a hot index/key, why should other keys get affected (why should whole throughput of cluster gets affected).

If whole throughput of cluster is getting affected in LWT/linearised TX, then what's the point of horizontally scalable database, does the same thing happens for cockroachDB?

Is there some benchmark done for throughput of a single key in LWT/linearised Tx for scylla/cassandra/cockroachDB?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9cO9OYhOtU

Why this video shows throughput being constant for LWT, why number of nodes in not taken into consideration as a variable for benchmarking?

Expectation: Throughput of a scylla/cassandra/cockroachDB cluster in LWT/linearised Tx should scale by horizontal scaling nodes in a cluster.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if what is bothering you is a "single key" (is this a single row, or a single partition?) if the throughput of LWT over many different keys. It is not true that Scylla/Cassandra (I don't know about cockroachdb) serializes LWT to different partition keys - these can, and do, proceed in parallel.

Comment: By single key I meant single row.

Comment: I know that LWT are only for single partition in a batch call. I was concerned about throughput of single row when used with LWT, I couldn't see any benchmarking number on this.

LWT should be processed in parallel and throughput of whole cluster should scale when new nodes are added.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9cO9OYhOtU
In the above video throughput using 3 nodes is shown with LWT. In the video no variables like hot key(single row) is used or if throughput scales when nodes are increased.

Comment: Currently in ScyllaDB (I don't know about the others), LWT is serialized at the partition level. This means that requests that go to different partitions are handled completely in parallel, and scaling the cluster scales the number of LWT requests you can do to different partitions exactly as you would expect. ScyllaDB currently serializes LWTs that go to different rows in the same partition which is planned to be fixed (see https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/6399) but in any case if there is no hot partition, that won't be a problem.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Your comment could be converted to answer as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently in ScyllaDB (I don't know about the others), LWT is serialized at the partition level. This means that requests that go to different partitions are handled in parallel, and scaling the cluster scales the number of LWT requests you can do to different partitions exactly as you would expect.

Currently, ScyllaDB needlessly serializes LWTs that go to **different rows** in the **same partition**. This is considered a bug and is planned to be fixed (see [#6399](http://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/6399)). But in any case, if there is no hot partition that a majority of updates go to rows in it, that won't cause a scalability problem.